# Xamarin.Android 4.8 & Servicestack issue

Tags: xamarin.android, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack with a Xamarin.Android/Mono for Android project.

Since updating to Xamarin.Android 4.8 if I use any linking I get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies..

I am using ServiceStack dlls from:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoDroid

Is the answer to this issue to compile the DLLs myself?

Additionally with Android 4.3 if I use a DTO with a property for an object which has a DateTime field I get an additional exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>    at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer.ToWcfJsonDate (DateTime dateTime) [0x00000]

Same code works with <4.3.  May not be related I realise.

Comment: Did you deploy the "System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" with your project?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you able to find a solution for this? Or did you simply not serialized DateTime to Json?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's a bug in Xamarin Android 4.8. 
See: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13686

It's out for the beta but hopefully they'll push out an update soon.